# Crossing UK border control while transiting through London Heathrow Airport

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, lhr

I know, I need to pass through UK border control if my transit time is before mid-night next day of my arrival and do not need visa as I have a valid permit to stay and live in Canada (source: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa). On my return to Canada through Heathrow, I have a connecting flight from Terminal 2, next day after 18 hours of my arrival at Terminal 4. My confusion is where shall I pass through the border control, at the arrival terminal (T4) or departure terminal (T2). Can I just walk toward border control, or I needed to be told about that?

Please help to reply.

This question is not about weather or not I need transit visa, I want to know at which terminal, arrival or departure, do I need to do my immigration stuff. I am sure, I wont get my borading pass from Heathrow to Canada at my point of origin (issuing boarding pass 24 hours before the flight is not possible).

Comment: Why do you *know* that you need to go through immigration? If you don't intend to leave the airport, you can definitely transfer from T4 to T2 using the bus and never see an immigration officer.
On the other hand, 18 hours might be overkill for staying at the airport, so if you want to go out and see London, you just go through immigration at T4 and you're out.

Comment: Also, having a permit to live in Canada is not the same as being a Canadian citizen, so I'm not sure if you should assume that you don't need a visa, you don't say which passport you have.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for taking your time to answer. Even if I do not intend cross the border control as per UK immigration rule "one must  pass through border control if her/his onward flight leaves on a different calendar day to when s/he arrive." Also, a Canadian permanent resident is eligible for "‘transit without visa" source https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: @ Giorgio you can check here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: Not a duplicate. Should be reopened.

Comment: Just to confirm @S.Bha, you're absolutely right. Also you'll cross the UK border at T4 - just follow the arrivals signs. When departing, there's no border control, and you just clear security at T2

Comment: Thanks @Coke. My plan is to cross immigration at T4. Then collect new boarding pass at T2 (probably next afternoon) and clear security before boarding the outbound flight.

Comment: @S.Bha That's the only way you can do it, due to the layout of the airport